# numpy logical_and: unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

Let us say I give you the following boolean arrays:

```
b1 = np.array([ True,  True, False,  True ])
b2 = np.array([ True, False, False,  True ])
b3 = np.array([ True,  True,  True, False ])
```

If you `AND` them together, you would expect the following result:

```
b4 = np.array([ True, False, False, False ])
```

Right? If not, please explain. If we agree, then, why does the following happen?

```
>>> np.logical_and(b1, b2, b3)
array([ True, False, False,  True ])
```

`np.logical_and(np.logical_and(b1, b2), b3)` does give the expected result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the [documentation of `np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). Like most of the NumPy operator functions, the third parameter is an `out` parameter, specifying a destination array. It is *not* an operand! Putting `b3` there will simply overwrite the contents of `b3`.

Using `&` is clearer and simpler in most cases:

```
b4 = b1 & b2 & b3
```

Comment: It is irrelevant when, as in the OP's case, the arrays are already boolean, but `&` calls `bitwise_and`, not `logical_and`.

Answer (score 6):

The third argument to `np.logical_and` is the optional `out` parameter, which stores the result of the operation.

That is, calling `np.logical_and(b1, b2, b3)` overwrites `b3` with the result of `np.logical_and(b1, b2)`.

Output arguments are useful for [determining output type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#output-type-determination) and general efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

`logical_and()` is a binary operator, for your question, you can use:

```
np.all([b1, b2, b3], axis=0)
np.logical_and.reduce([b1, b2, b3], axis=0)
```

Comment: Which one is most efficient?